# JMeter, how to assert a dynamic value, that contains special characters using response assertions

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a value with the following format [aadrzr@r2za$l919d@ldzkld], but when asserting this value in the response assertion, I am getting a failed response assertion. Since it contains special characters.

How I can solve this. Notice that the value is auto generated and I don't know what value format will be retieved.

**Example:**
"key": "aadrzr@r2za$l919d@ldzkld",

**Response assertion :**
failed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the value is "auto generated" what are you going to "assert" here?

The presence of `key` property can be checked using [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) or [JSON JMESPath Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Going forward please consider including at least partial response and your Assertion setup as without being able to reproduce the issue we are not able to help as well

Answer (score 0):

One approach to resolve this issue is to use the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter. The Regular Expression Extractor allows you to extract dynamic values from a response, and it can handle special characters.

Here's how you can use it to extract the value from the response:

1. Add the Regular Expression Extractor as a post-processor element to the HTTP Request Sampler that generates the response containing the value.
2. In the Regular Expression Extractor, configure the following fields:

- Reference Name: a variable name to store the extracted value (e.g. extractedValue)
- Regular Expression: the pattern that matches the value in the response (e.g. "key":\s*"([^"]+)" in this case)
- Template: $1$
- Match No.: 1

3. In the Response Assertion, use the extracted value as the "Pattern to Test".

- Pattern Matching Rules: choose "Equals"
- Pattern: ${extractedValue}

This way, you can assert the value with special characters even though it's dynamic and not known in advance.